# Github login from Unity3d usable from smartphone & standalone

Tags: unity-game-engine, github-api

Have been posting around without success :

- https://forum.unity.com/threads/github-login-token.521941/
- https://platform.github.community/t/login-from-ios-download-a-single-file-using-unity3d-engine/5325

I am making a container app for iOS using Unity3d.

The user should login to GitHUB.
Should access to a list of file (mostly image file type).
download possible.
Well so far…

I have made a github app, then I have the client_id and the client_secret.
Making research I found this url works to request permission to user for your app :

```
url = “https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scrop=user:email&client_id=” + client_id
```

Well if you copy past the url with your client ID directly into the browser it will redirect you to your home page url with a form like this:

https://www.yourhomepage.com/?code=2ce706d933c922d7f22c

The code always change on each login or session.

Finally back to Unity, you can use a WWWForm, etc… with the following data to get receive the token :

```
url = https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token2
client_id = xxxx (from your app detail)
client_secret = xxxx (from your app detail)
code = xxxx (from the previous step.
```

The big question is how could the login could be done via wwwForm and it it exists.
Then file request from a Private repository.